# wpf ListItem SelectedValue Object is always null

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have a simple ListBox and a TextBox as under.I want to display the selectedvalue property of Listbox in the textbox,but my ViewModel's selected object is always null.
What am i missing here?

My XAML

```
<StackPanel>
    <Canvas>
        <TextBox x:Name="TxtMail" Width="244" FontSize="14" Canvas.Left="36" Canvas.Top="34" Height="20" Text="{Binding CurrentRec.Name,Mode=OneWay}" />
        <ListBox x:Name="AllMatching" Width="{Binding ElementName=TxtMail,Path=Width}" Height="100" Canvas.Top="54" Canvas.Left="36"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentRec,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValue="Name" SelectedValuePath="Name" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
        <Button Content="Test" x:Name="cmdtest" Click="cmdtest_Click"/>
    </Canvas>
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class VM_Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public int p_ID;
    public double p_SP, p_CP;
    public string p_Name;
    public List<DM_Data> AllData;

    public DM_Data CurrentRec;
    public VM_Data()
    {
        LoadData();
    }
    public int ID
    {
        get { return p_ID; }
        set
        {
            if (p_ID != value)
            {
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("ID");
                p_ID = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public double SP
    {

        get { return p_SP; }
        set
        {
            if (p_SP != value)
            {
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SP");
                p_SP = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public double CP
    {
        get { return p_CP; }
        set
        {
            if (p_CP != value)
            {
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("CP");
                p_CP = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return p_Name; }
        set
        {
            if (p_Name != value)
            {
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Name");
                p_Name = value;
            }
        }
    }
    private void LoadData()
    {
        AllData = new List<DM_Data>();
        string[] strNames = "Jatinder;Shashvat;shashikala;shamsher;shahid;justin;jatin;jolly;ajay;ahan;vijay;suresh;namita;nisha;negar;zenith;zan;zen;zutshi;harish;hercules;harman;ramesh;shashank;mandeep;aman;amandeep;amarjit;asim;akshay;amol;ritesh;ritivik;riz;samana;samaira;bhagwandass;bhagwan;bhawna;bhavna".Split(';');
        for(int i=0;i<=strNames.GetUpperBound(0);i++)
        {
            DM_Data NewRec = new DM_Data();
            NewRec.CP = new Random().Next(200, 400);
            NewRec.SP = new Random().Next(1, 10);
            NewRec.ID = i + 1;
            NewRec.Name = strNames[i];
            AllData.Add(NewRec);
        }
        AllData = AllData.OrderBy(item => item.Name).ToList();
    }
    private void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string Property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Property));
        }
    }
}
```

My DataModel

```
public class DM_Data
{
    public int p_ID;
    public double p_SP, p_CP;
    public string p_Name;

    public int ID
    {
        get { return p_ID; }
        set { p_ID = value; }
    }

    public double SP
    {
        get { return p_SP; }
        set { p_SP = value; }
    }
    public double CP
    {
        get { return p_CP; }
        set { p_CP = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return p_Name; }
        set { p_Name = value; }
    }
```

MainWindow.Xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    VM_Data ViewModel;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
         ViewModel = new VM_Data();
        this.DataContext = ViewModel;
        AllMatching.ItemsSource = ViewModel.AllData;
    }

    private void cmdtest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DM_Data crec = ViewModel.CurrentRec;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Properties and remove this `SelectedValue="Name" SelectedValuePath="Name"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CurrentRec` must be a *property* that raises the `PropertyChanged` event:

```
private DM_Data _currentRec;
public DM_Data CurrentRec
{
    get { return _currentRec; }
    set { _currentRec = value; RaisePropertyChangedEvent("CurrentRec"); }
}
```

In the code you have posted, it is a `field` and you cannot bind to fields:

```
public DM_Data CurrentRec;
```

Comment: ahhh..tx again mm8...not that i didn't know it..but had missed it....:-).

Answer (score 0):

**You can't bind to fields!** `CurrentRec` must be a property. At now it is a field.

1. Why do you set `ItemsSource` in code-behind? Set it in XAML.
2. You should call `RaisePropertyChangedEvent` **after** you've changed backing field, not before.
3. It is not right pattern for events raising: `if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Property)); }` You need to save event delegate to variable first or use `?.Invoke`.
4. Don't create new instances of `Random` on every iteration of loop because you will get equal values. Create the only one outside of the loop and use it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is kind of `MVVM`, but not really.

Here is a quick fix anyway:

Please take a look at the `Bindings`.

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Canvas>
            <TextBox x:Name="TxtMail" Width="244" FontSize="14" Canvas.Left="36" Canvas.Top="34" Height="20" Text="{Binding ElementName=AllMatching, Path=SelectedItem.Name}" />
            <ListBox x:Name="AllMatching" 
                     Width="{Binding ElementName=TxtMail,Path=Width}" 
                     Height="100" 
                     Canvas.Top="54" 
                     Canvas.Left="36"  
                     DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                     SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentRec,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
            <Button Content="Test" x:Name="cmdtest" Click="cmdtest_Click"/>
        </Canvas>
    </StackPanel>
```

I think you get the idea at: `Text="{Binding ElementName=AllMatching, Path=SelectedItem.Name}"`.

**Aditional Information**

**First:**
You fire to early dude. Please first assign the value and then say its changed.

```
       if (p_Name != value)
        {
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Name");
            p_Name = value;
        }
```

**Second:**
Use a `ObservableCollection<DM_Data>` to let your `ListBox` know about changes.

**Third:**
Use the posibility of `Binding`

Remove `AllMatching.ItemsSource = ViewModel.AllData;` and go like

```
        <ListBox x:Name="AllMatching"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllData}"
                 ...
                 />
```

And after all of this - please man check out some tutorials. And also refactor your code from `VM_Data` to `DataViewModel` thank you sir.